# optimise mysql join query

Tags: mysql, sql, testlink

following mysql query taking more time to fetch results so i need help to optimise

```
         SELECT status,
                   count(status) AS COUNT,
                   build_id,
                   results_bu.name,
                   results_bu.creation_ts,
                   results_bu.release_date
            FROM
              (SELECT NHTC.parent_id AS tsuite_id,
                      NHTC.id AS tcase_id,
                      NHTC.name AS name,
                      TPTCV.tcversion_id,
                      TPTCV.platform_id,
                      E.build_id,
                      E.tcversion_number AS VERSION,
                      TCV.tc_external_id AS external_id,
                      E.id AS executions_id,
                      E.status AS status,
                      (TPTCV.urgency * TCV.importance) AS urg_imp
               FROM testplan_tcversions TPTCV 
    /* GO FOR Absolute LATEST exec ID On BUILD,PLATFORM */
               JOIN
                 (SELECT EE.tcversion_id,
                         EE.testplan_id,
                         EE.platform_id,
                         EE.build_id,
                         MAX(EE.id) AS id
                  FROM executions EE
                  WHERE EE.testplan_id=13954
                    AND EE.build_id IN
                      (SELECT id
                       FROM builds
                       WHERE testplan_id = 13954
                         AND active=1
                         AND (creation_ts BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2015-05-10'))
                       ORDER BY name ASC)
                  GROUP BY EE.tcversion_id,
                           EE.testplan_id,
                           EE.platform_id,
                           EE.build_id) AS LEBBP ON LEBBP.testplan_id = TPTCV.testplan_id
               AND LEBBP.platform_id = TPTCV.platform_id
               AND LEBBP.tcversion_id = TPTCV.tcversion_id
               AND LEBBP.testplan_id = 13954
     /* Get execution status WRITTEN on DB */
               JOIN executions E ON E.id = LEBBP.id
               AND E.build_id = LEBBP.build_id
     /* Get Test Case info from Test Case Version */
               JOIN nodes_hierarchy NHTCV ON NHTCV.id = TPTCV.tcversion_id
     /* Get Test Suite info from Test Case  */
               JOIN nodes_hierarchy NHTC ON NHTC.id = NHTCV.parent_id
     /* Get Test Case Version attributes */
               JOIN tcversions TCV ON TCV.id = E.tcversion_id
               WHERE TPTCV.testplan_id=13954
                 AND E.build_id IN
                   (SELECT id
                    FROM builds
                    WHERE testplan_id = 13954
                      AND active=1
                      AND (creation_ts BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2015-05-10'))
                    ORDER BY name ASC)
               UNION ALL
     /* sqlUnion Test suites - not run */
  SELECT NHTC.parent_id AS tsuite_id,     
                    NHTC.id AS tcase_id,
                    NHTC.name AS name,
                    TPTCV.tcversion_id,
                    TPTCV.platform_id,
                    BU.id AS build_id,
                    TCV.VERSION,
                    TCV.tc_external_id AS external_id,
                    COALESCE(E.id,-1) AS executions_id,
                    COALESCE(E.status,'n') AS status,
                    (TPTCV.urgency * TCV.importance) AS urg_imp
               FROM testplan_tcversions TPTCV 
    /* Needed to be able to put a value on build_id on output set  */
               JOIN builds BU ON BU.id IN
                 (SELECT id
                  FROM builds
                  WHERE testplan_id = 13954
                    AND active=1
                    AND (creation_ts BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2015-05-10'))
                  ORDER BY name ASC)
     /* GO FOR Absolute LATEST exec ID On BUILD,PLATFORM */
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (SELECT EE.tcversion_id,
                         EE.testplan_id,
                         EE.platform_id,
                         EE.build_id,
                         MAX(EE.id) AS id
                  FROM executions EE
                  WHERE EE.testplan_id=13954
                    AND EE.build_id IN
                      (SELECT id
                       FROM builds
                       WHERE testplan_id = 13954
                         AND active=1
                         AND (creation_ts BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2015-05-10'))
                       ORDER BY name ASC)
                  GROUP BY EE.tcversion_id,
                           EE.testplan_id,
                           EE.platform_id,
                           EE.build_id) AS LEBBP ON LEBBP.testplan_id = TPTCV.testplan_id
               AND LEBBP.platform_id = TPTCV.platform_id
               AND LEBBP.tcversion_id = TPTCV.tcversion_id
               AND LEBBP.build_id = BU.id
               AND LEBBP.testplan_id = 13954
     /* Get execution status WRITTEN on DB */
               LEFT OUTER JOIN executions E ON E.build_id = LEBBP.build_id
               AND E.testplan_id = TPTCV.testplan_id
               AND E.platform_id = TPTCV.platform_id
               AND E.tcversion_id = TPTCV.tcversion_id
     /* Get Test Case info from Test Case Version */
               JOIN nodes_hierarchy NHTCV ON NHTCV.id = TPTCV.tcversion_id
     /* Get Test Suite info from Test Case  */
               JOIN nodes_hierarchy NHTC ON NHTC.id = NHTCV.parent_id
     /* Get Test Case Version attributes */
               JOIN tcversions TCV ON TCV.id = TPTCV.tcversion_id
               WHERE TPTCV.testplan_id=13954
                 AND BU.id IN
                   (SELECT id
                    FROM builds
                    WHERE testplan_id = 13954
                      AND active=1
                      AND (creation_ts BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2015-05-10'))
                    ORDER BY name ASC)
    /* Get REALLY NOT RUN => BOTH LEBBP.id AND E.id NULL  */
                 AND E.id IS NULL
                 AND LEBBP.id IS NULL) AS RESULT
            LEFT OUTER JOIN builds AS results_bu ON results_bu.id=RESULT.build_id
            GROUP BY status,
                     build_id;
```

results for EXPLAIN as follows

```
id  select_type     table          type          possible_keys                          key                             key_len ref                             rows        Extra
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>      ALL                                                                                                                         32768       Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY         results_bu      eq_ref          PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                             4   result.build_id 1   
2   DERIVED         <derived3>      ALL                                                                                                                         32229       Using where
2   DERIVED         NHTCV           eq_ref          PRIMARY,pid_m_nodeorder             PRIMARY                             4   LEBBP.tcversion_id                      1   
2   DERIVED         NHTC            eq_ref          PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.NHTCV.parent_id        1   
2   DERIVED         TPTCV           eq_ref          testplan_tcversions_tplan_tcversion testplan_tcversions_tplan_tcversion 12  LEBBP.tcversion_id,LEBBP.platform_id     1  
2   DERIVED         E               eq_ref          PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                             4   LEBBP.id                                 1      Using where
2   DERIVED         TCV             eq_ref          PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.E.tcversion_id          1  
4   DEPENDENT 
    SUBQUERY        builds          unique_subquery PRIMARY,name,testplan_id            PRIMARY                             4   func                                     1      Using where
3   DERIVED         EE              ref             executions_idx1                     executions_idx1                     4                                           135350  Using where; Using index
3   DERIVED         BB              eq_ref          PRIMARY,name,testplan_id            PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.EE.build_id            1       Using where
5   UNION           BU                              index                               testplan_id                         4                                           569     Using where; Using index
5   UNION           TPTCV           ref             testplan_tcversions_tplan_tcversion testplan_tcversions_tplan_tcversion 4                                           1472    
5   UNION           TCV             eq_ref          PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.TPTCV.tcversion_id     1   
5   UNION           NHTCV           eq_ref          PRIMARY,pid_m_nodeorder             PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.TPTCV.tcversion_id     1   
5   UNION           NHTC            eq_ref          PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.NHTCV.parent_id        1   
5   UNION           <derived6>      ALL                                                                                                                                 32229   Using where
5   UNION           E               ref             executions_idx1                     executions_idx1                     16 bitnami_testlink.TPTCV.tcversion_id,
                                                                                                                                bitnami_testlink.TPTCV.platform_id,
                                                                                                                                LEBBP.build_id                           1      Using where; Not exists
8   DEPENDENT 
    SUBQUERY        builds          unique_subquery PRIMARY,name,testplan_id            PRIMARY                             4   func                                     1      Using where
7   DEPENDENT
    SUBQUERY        builds          unique_subquery PRIMARY,name,testplan_id            PRIMARY                             4   func                                     1      Using where
6   DERIVED         EE              ref             executions_idx1                     executions_idx1                     4                                           135350  Using where; Using index
6   DERIVED         BB              eq_ref          PRIMARY,name,testplan_id            PRIMARY                             4   bitnami_testlink.EE.build_id            1       Using where
    UNION RESULT    <union2,5>      ALL
```

Actually we are trying to get how many number of execution records passed, failed between period of time for selected Test plan from test link database

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Try the UNION ALL's different selects one by one.

Comment: For help with performance we typically need to see proper DDLs and the results of an EXPLAIN.

Comment: ... that said, there appears to be huge amounts of redundancy here. A rewrite from scratch might be what's needed. But to help with that we'd really need a functioning data set and a desired result.

Comment: @Ram next time you place sql like that, use something like [sqlformat](http://sqlformat.org/) so people can understand/read it better.

Comment: Aside from your original horribly formatted query, in plain language, what is it you are trying to actually do...  such as... For test plan X that is active and within a date range provided, I need ...  The union all is to also account for .... that might have otherwise been excluded from ...  (again, just an example).  Do descriptions like this for better clarification.

Comment: @Ram for starter you can replace the SELECT statements placed inside IN(...) clauses by JOINS .. I see many keys to make joins at ..

Comment: Thanks for all your comments!! and i have updated my question with results of EXPLAIN